# Different color for code comments and XML comments in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I've noticed that in C# XML comments and code comments can have different colors by changing the settings in Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Display Items:
- Comment: controls code comments
- XML comment: controls XML comments

This works well in C#

```
///<summary>This XML comment is green</summary>

//This code comment is red
```

But not in VB.NET

```
'''<summary>This XML comment appears red too even though it's configured as green</summary>

'This code comment is red
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm using Visual studio 2005

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess it's a VS 2005 problem. I need to upgrade!

Comment: Yes it was a VS 2005 issue. I've updated to VS 2010 and it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The coloring settings for VB and C# are different for each language.

Here's a partial list of the corresponding settings between the two:

```
C#                 VB
Comment            Comment
XML Doc Attribute  VB XML Attribute
XML Doc Comment    VB XML Comment (the second one)
XML Doc Tag        VB XML Doc Tag
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which IDE you're using to develop in.  For Visual Studio 2010, Click on Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors.  In the Show settings for drop down list, select Text Editor.

In Display Items: select Comment. This will change the color of the comments within code.

Next in Display Items: select VB XML Comment.  This will change the color of the XML comments which are used. There may be 2 items with the same name; I had to change the second one.